# Impala and reading special characters

Tags: impala

We have Impala ODBC connection in `odbc.ini` file and have problem to see some special characters correctly (danish characters) in tables when we are connected to a database.

Is there any options that can be defined to change the encoding (in the following example)?

Here is an example of the ODBC connection we have:

```
[Impala]
Description=Cloudera ODBC Driver for Impala (32-bit) DSN
Driver=/opt/cloudera/impalaodbc/lib/64/libclouderaimpalaodbc64.so
HOST=dd300en09.bbd.net
PORT=21053
Database=default
AuthMech=1
KrbFQDN=dd300bn09.bbd.net
KrbRealm=ABC.DEF.COM
KrbServiceName=impala
UID=
PWD=
CAIssuedCertNamesMismatch=1
TSaslTransportBufSize=1000
RowsFetchedPerBlock=10000
SocketTimeout=0
StringColumnLength=32767
UseNativeQuery=0
```

Comment: You could check if the data encoding is good **and** if the ODBC configuration match the data encoding.